# How can I make the text to show all the 8 digit numbers and clear the text after that?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class SecurityKeypadSystem : MonoBehaviour
{
    [Header("References")]
    // rather let this class control the display text
    [SerializeField] private TextMesh _text;

    [Header("Settings")]
    // also rather let this class control the length of a code
    [SerializeField] private int _codeLength = 8;

    [Header("Debugging")]
    [SerializeField] private GameObject[] _keyPadNumbers;
    [SerializeField] private List<int> _code = new List<int>();

    // This will be invoked once the code length has reached the target length
    public event Action<int> OnCodeComplete;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    private void Start()
    {
        var KeyPadNumbersParent = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("KeypadParent").GetComponentsInChildren<Transform>(true);
        foreach (Transform child in KeyPadNumbersParent)
        {
            if (child.gameObject.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>() != null)
            {
                var securityKeypadKeys = child.gameObject.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
                securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
                securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed += HandleKeyPressed;
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        // just for completeness you should always remove callbacks as soon as they are not needed anymore
        // in order to avoid any exceptions
        foreach (var keyPadNumber in _keyPadNumbers)
        {
            var securityKeypadKeys = keyPadNumber.GetComponent<SecurityKeypadKeys>();
            securityKeypadKeys.onKeyPressed -= HandleKeyPressed;
        }
    }

    // this is called when a keypad key was pressed
    private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
    {
        // add the value to the list
        _code.Add(value);

        _text.text += value.ToString();

        // Check if the code has reached the target length
        // if not do nothing
        if (_code.Count <= _codeLength) return;

        // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
        var exponent = _code.Count;
        float finalCode = 0;
        foreach (var digit in _code)
        {
            finalCode =digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
            exponent--;
        }

        // invoke the callback event
        OnCodeComplete?.Invoke((int)finalCode);

        // and reset the code
        ResetCode();
    }

    // Maybe you later want an option to clear the code field from the outside as well
    public void ResetCode()
    {
        _code.Clear();
        _text.text = "";
    }

    // also clear the input if this gets disabled
    private void OnDisable()
    {
        ResetCode();
    }
}
```

The code length is 8 and this line was only < and I changed it to <=

```
if (_code.Count <= _codeLength) return;
```

So now if I type for example 12345678 it will show the 8 digits but to make it clear I need to type another 9 digit and it will not show the 9 digit but I must press on another 9 digit to make it clear.

I want that if I type for example 12345678 or 22222222 show all the eight numbers then clear.
Changing from < to <= show the eight digits but to make it clear I need to add/press on nine digit.

And even not to reset at all let's say I'm not calling the ResetCode method, just make it that if I type show the eight numbers 12345678 and don't the option to keep add and show numbers. The code length is 8 it can be 2 or 100 but it should show the code length.

Comment: Don't return.  when you check `_code.Count` fall through if count == `_codeLength`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this:

```
private void HandleKeyPressed(int value)
{
    // add the value to the list
    _code.Add(value);

    _text.text += value.ToString();

    // Check if the code has reached the target length
    // if yes prcoess further
    if (_code.Count == _codeLength)
    {
      // if it reached the length combine all numbers into one int
      var exponent = _code.Count;
      float finalCode = 0;
      foreach (var digit in _code)
      {
          finalCode =digit * Mathf.Pow(10, exponent);
          exponent--;
      }

      // invoke the callback event
      OnCodeComplete?.Invoke((int)finalCode);

      // and reset the code
      ResetCode();
    }
}
```